# Rails constants used for routes are not reloaded in development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm experiencing what I think is a pretty common issue which I have experienced before although I can't seem to figure out a solution for it this time around.

I have routes whose definitions are dependent on subclasses of `Item` loading as shown (actual routing is way too complicated to post):

```
match ":style/:item_type/search", to: "items#search", constraints: 
  { 
    item_type: Item.searchable
  }
```

Please note that `Item` is not a Rails/AR model, it's just a Ruby class. The `Item` class has the following two class methods:

```
def self.all_types
  return @all_types if @all_types && @all_types.any?

  Dir.glob(File.join(Rails.root, 'app', 'models', 'items', '*.rb')).each do |descendant|
    require descendant
  end
  @all_types = self.descendants
end

def self.searchable
  all_types.select{ |i| i.searchable? }
end
```

Basically, that is we require each file and then ask a class method if you are searchable or not which returns true or false obviously.

My problem is that even this method fails, if I insert a debugger statement just below the `Dir.glob` block and check the value of `self.descendants` there I find an empty array.

Note that the ONLY happens after I edit any relevant file and try to continue using my server in development mode. That is, if I edit `item.rb` or a subclass `awesome_item.rb` the @all_types array is empty and my routes collapse.

I hope this is enough information. I've tried reading the docs on autoload but either I don't understand how they could benefit me or it isn't the solution I'm looking for.

Comment: Does the issue persist if you set ` config.cache_classes = true` in your `config/environments/development.rb` file?

Comment: Does the issue persist if you remove the `return @all_types if @all_types ...` line? What if you replace `require descendant` by `load descendant`? (just a hunch, don't do this in production)

Comment: it works with cache_classes of course, but I can't use that, I need dev mode to work like normal for the rest of the team. Removing that line does not fix my issue

Comment: That comment was not my answer. I was gathering information in order to try and help. You don't seem to appreciate this, though, so I'll better not bother you any longer.

Comment: What?! I answered your questions in two separate sentences. I wasn't trying to be snippy, sorry YOU read it like that.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I was a bit tired. I mostly saw the "you didn't solve my problem" part. Will do better next time :)